# File seems to be timestamped before it is created

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ext4, filemtime

Following test is always failing (this runs on a linux system, the question is not about other OSes):

```
    from time import time
    from decimal import Decimal
    from pathlib import Path

    def test_timing():
        start = Decimal(time())
        p = Path(__file__).parent / 'testfile.txt'  # does not yet exist
        p.touch()
        mt = p.stat().st_mtime
        p.unlink()  # unlinked before the failing assert
>       assert start <= mt
E       AssertionError: assert Decimal('1640930671.75709438323974609375') <= 1640930671.7534654
```

The gap is always about 3 to 7 ms.

How is it possible that `Decimal(time())` at start returns a timestamp that's **later** than the file that is created two lines after it?

Is there an offset between python timestamps and the linux' ones? Does python proceed creating the file before the `Decimal(time())` call is finished? What am I missing here?

EDIT: I should have mentionned it's ext4 filesystem.

Comment: Filesystems don't store timestamps with infinite precision; the original FAT filesystem had a *two second* granularity!  Apparently the one you're using will at least sometimes round up to its next representable timestamp.

Comment: That's not it.  ext4 stores timestamps to the nanosecond.  I'll post the real answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ext4 filesystem uses `current_fs_time` to grab the kernel timestamp.  For efficiency, the kernel timestamp is a cached value, which is only updated at scheduler intervals, which is about 10ms.  So, the time could be as much as 10ms old by the time it gets stored.

As a side note, there is no point in converting the timestamp to `Decimal`.  The value from C is a double, which only holds about 17 digits.  That means you get down to microseconds.  Converting to `Decimal` does not gain you any additional precision; the other digits are essentially random.

Comment: Nice to know, that's something that would have been hard to debug unless you know the answer ;)

Comment: Many thanks! So, I'll just remove the useless `Decimal` and simply add a `time.sleep(0.015)` for instance, to remove the problem. Speed is not a problem in my case.

Comment: I'm curious to know how this could ever be a problem in any way.  This is a picayune implementation detail.  If you need to record the creation time of the file, then use `p.stat().st_mtime` and not `time.time()`.